# How do you find the solutions to the vector field $W(x,y,z)?$

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, multivariable-calculus, vector-analysis, vector-fields

> How do you find the solutions (streamlines and integral surfaces) for $W(x,y,z)=\big(x\log x,-y\log y, -z\log z\big)$ for $0<x,y,z<1?$

I was able to plot the streamlines of $W:$

[image]

I can solve $W(x,y)$ exactly but am unsure how to approach the generalized problem in 3d.

Comment: The system is separated into three independent equations. Each equation is a separated, can be solved easily. What's is the dificulty?

Comment: I think I can write the system of equations out, but I'm not sure how to go from there. For $W(x,y)$ I'm getting $\frac{dy}{dx}=\frac{-y\log y}{x\log x}.$

Comment: @BlackMild could you make an answer? WIll there be integral surfaces for this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With "streamlines" I suppose you mean a (maximal) solution of the equation $$\frac{d}{dt}(x(t),y(t),z(t))=W(x(t),y(t),z(t))\\=(W_x(x(t),y(t),z(t)),W_y(x(t),y(t),z(t)),W_z(x(t),y(t),z(t)))$$
or the set of all reparametrizations of that solution or the image of that solution. Well, the system of equations
$$\frac{d}{dt}x(t)=W_x(x(t),y(t),z(t))=x(t)\log(x(t))\\
\frac{d}{dt}y(t)=W_y(x(t),y(t),z(t))=-y(t)\log(y(t))\\
\frac{d}{dt}z(t)=W_z(x(t),y(t),z(t))=-z(t)\log(z(t))$$
decouples and has the solution $(x(t),y(t),z(t))=(x(0)^{\exp(t)},y(0)^{\exp(-t)},z(0)^{\exp(-t)})$.

As for "integral surfaces", I suppose you mean a family of 2D surface which partition $\mathbb{R}^3$ and with each member of that family intersecting at 90° with each of the above integral curves. If we could find a pair of functions $f,g:\mathbb{R}^3 \to \mathbb{R}$ so that $W=f\nabla g$, then the contours of $g$, i.e. $\{x\in \mathbb{R}^3|\,g(x)=C\}_{C\in \mathbb{R}}$, would provide a formula for that family of surfaces. In this case we can just take $f\equiv 1$ and $$g(x,y,z):=\frac{1}{4}\left(x^2(2\log(x)-1)-y^2(2\log(y)-1)-z^2(2\log(z)-1)\right).$$
(I found $g$ by adding the anti-derivative of $W_x$ w.r.t. $x$, the anti-derivative of $W_y$ w.r.t. $y$ and the anti-derivative of $W_z$ w.r.t. $z$)

Comment: Thank you so much for this answer. I was actually looking for integral surfaces tangent to the streamlines/integral curves...would you mind adding the equation for these?

Comment: That sounds like a subjective notion to me, geocalc33: there are many ways to thread adjacent streamlines together into a surface. That should be intuitively clear.

Comment: Okay thanks. For $W(x,y)$ we get the solution $(e^{-\exp(t)},e^{-\exp(-t)}.$ For $W(x,y,z)$ is $(e^{-\exp(t)},e^{-\exp(-t)},e^{-\exp(-t)})$ also a solution?

Comment: It's a particular solution, i.e. for the initial condition (x(0),y(0),z(0))=(1,1,1). It concerns (a parametrization of) one particular streamline, but by no means does that formula describe any of the other streamlines.

Comment: Will you not accept my answer? Just click the checkmark to the left of my answer if you think I have answered your question.

Comment: I accepted it, but you wrote $(x(t),y(t),z(t))=(x(0)^{\exp(t)},y(0)^{-\exp(t)},z(0)^{-\exp(t)}).$ Shouldn't it actually be this? $(x(t),y(t),z(t))=(x(0)^{\pm\exp(t)},y(0)^{\pm\exp(-t)},z(0)^{\pm\exp(-t)})$

Comment: I should indeed have written the minuses inside the inner exponential, but I don't know where you get the $\pm$'s from.

Comment: I'm just re-writing it in a different way with $e$ as the base: $(e^{\pm a \exp(t) }, e^{\pm b \exp(-t)} , e^{\pm c \exp(-t)})$ for some real parameters $a,b,c$

Comment: I think $W$ maybe Killing for a semi-riemannian metric $g$, and the pair $(W,g)$ maybe equivalent to $\Bbb M^{2,1}.$ Is that plausible?